# Is there a way to nest complexTypes without a wrapper tag?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a `<choice>` that I need to pull out of its current element into its own type (so that it can be referenced by other `complexTypes`). Is there a way to do that without needing a wrapper tag?

This is what I have so far:

The complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyType">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="type1"/>
            <xs:element ref="type2"/>
        </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

And referencing it

```
<xs:complexType name="AdaptabilitySettingMetadataBase" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <!-- other elements -->
        <xs:element name="MyTypeInClass" type="MyType"
                    minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This works, but only allows me to put the `type1` and `type2`s within the tag `MyTypeInClass`, which I don't want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xs:group` rather than `xs:complexType` to achieve your goal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtCS/v02_02_00"
           targetNamespace="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtCS/v02_02_00"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="elem1"/>
  <xs:element name="elem2"/>

  <xs:group name="MyType">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element ref="elem1"/>
      <xs:element ref="elem2"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:complexType name="AdaptabilitySettingMetadataBase" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- other elements -->
      <xs:group ref="MyType" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>     
</xs:schema>
```