# How to utilize complexType without wrapper element in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, deserialization, xsd-validation, xml-validation

How do I write an XSD for this XML-1 (simplified examples):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
  <username>Albert Einstein</username>
  <!-- no wrapper element for address -->
  <street>Main Street</street>
  <city>Ghost Town</city>
  <state>Up State</state>
</user>
```

instead of the more logical XML-2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
  <username>Albert Einstein</username>
  <!-- with wrapper element for address -->
  <address>
    <street>Main Street</street>
    <city>Ghost Town</city>
    <state>Up State</state>
  </address>
</user>
```

where `username` stands for all fields that are not part of the database table for addresses, which is a table that I cannot just change to include more fields,

with some kind of record type for the `address` fields like this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="user" type="user" />
  <!-- =========================================== -->
  <xsd:complexType name="user">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <!-- username stands for all non-address fields -->
      <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" />
      <!-- wrapper element for the address fields -->
      <xsd:element name="address" type="address_Type" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!-- =========================================== -->
  <xsd:complexType name="address_Type">
    <!-- the columns of the database table for addresses -->
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Using the tools in Visual Studio I verified that XML-2 validates with the XSD, but XML-1 does not. How do I improve the "problem line" in the XSD? Apparently, you cannot write in the XSD an element without name:

```
<xsd:element type="address_type" />
```

I need to include the `complexType` for the `address` fields without the enclosing

```
<address>
```

tag.

Reason for this question is that this XSD will be useful to create a C# class for the database table `address` using xsd.exe in the visual studio sdk.

I will have to process many different format XML's, with most of them having address data within the address wrapper element. It is easy to expand the XSD to validate those XML's. The problem is with XML with address data without wrapper element, that seem not to be validatable with XSD with the complexType Address_Type. Unless someone smarter than myself sees a solution.

Because of the relation between the complexType and the structure of the database table, I cannot just add the username field to the complexType. Username really stands for all fields that are NOT in the address table.

I am open for all suggestions. Even after doing quite some XSD stuff I still feel like a beginner and I am not even sure if using xsd:sequence is needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** New Q/A that addresses @Roland's refined requirements has been created here:

- [How to model database tables in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66286743/290085)

*Original, outdated answer and updates follow...*

---

If you do not want a wrapper `address` element, you can simply not define one, and place its content model directly within the content model of `user`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="user" type="user" />
  <xsd:complexType name="user">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

---

Per your comment, you don't want to do the above; you want to reuse the elements in `address_Type`.

There is no direct way to say what you want, but you could have the `user` complex type extend the `address_Type` complex type.  This would allow you to add the `username` element to those elements already appearing in `address_type` (although it would read rather unnaturally to extend an address in such a way).

- [Example of extending complex types in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50785402/290085)

To reuse parts of content models more naturally, consider using `xs:group`.  For examples, see

- [Refer to specific element of an XSD model group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47017931/290085)
- [Is there a way to nest complexTypes without a wrapper tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42445442/290085)

Comment: Your answer does not utilize the complexType for the address fields. The question is: how can I refer in the XSD to the complexType for address without needing the <address> tag in the xml? Should I change the title for this question? I am not sure about the best jargon for this question. And, actually, it is not that I do not want the wrapper element, but that others are too lazy to apply the wrapper element. Things are much easier with the wrapper element. The question is how to cope without that wrapper element? The xsd will have the complexType for other xml's with wrapper element.

Comment: Answer updated to address your follow-up.

Comment: Thanks for update but username stands for all the fields that are not in the address type, which stands for the formal representation of some database table. I need to process the set of address fields NEXT to non-address fields. I cannot just change the database table Address with the extra username field. It seems that the XSD with complexType for Address_Type is not possible without the wrapper element. On the other hand, there are so many smart people here who might still have a better solution.

Comment: I believe neither the `xs:complexType` extension nor the `xs:group` suggestions depend upon `username` being the sole element among those you wish to supplement.  Have you read the Q/A I suggested regarding `xs:group`?  I've added another Q/A link regarding `xs:complexType` extension too.

Comment: I did learn a lot from the linked questions, hence the upvote. After I posted a better formulated question and got clearer answer there, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66286743/1845672 , I understood that this answer has indeed the solution, so I accepted.

Comment: Not just fixing a problem, but it gives so much satisfaction if programming works, especially if it is an elegant workaround for a "sub-optimal" design from someone else. I could not resist trying it out on my free weekend. But don't worry, I will get these hours compensated :-)