# How to model database tables in XSD?

Tags: xml, database-design, xsd, reusability, complextype

It seems simple to model a database table for, say, addresses, like this in an XSD:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="address_Type">
    <!-- the columns of the database table for addresses -->
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Then you can define an XML format using this tabel plus some other unrelated data, say, a user name, like this:

```
  <xsd:element name="user" type="user" />
  <!-- =========================================== -->
  <xsd:complexType name="user">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <!-- username stands for all non-address fields -->
      <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" />
      <!-- wrapper element for the address fields -->
      <xsd:element name="address" type="address_Type" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

and the XML could be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
  <username>Albert Einstein</username>
  <!-- with wrapper element for address -->
  <address>
    <street>Main Street</street>
    <city>Ghost Town</city>
    <state>Up State</state>
  </address>
</user>
```

This method is easily extensible to XML's with a list of addresses, or with an address record combined with records from other tables. One XSD could cover lots of XML formats this way.

However, what about someone who thinks, **why do I need that stupid "address" wrapper element if I only include 1 instance of an address object**, to arrive at this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
  <username>Albert Einstein</username>
  <!-- no wrapper element for address -->
  <street>Main Street</street>
  <city>Ghost Town</city>
  <state>Up State</state>
</user>
```

To me it seems that now we cannot use the same complexType for address as in the XSD above.

In my company, the IT organization is dispersed, and if I start yelling "you should add the wrapper element", I might just get a sore throat. Or a headache. So it is up to me to improve my XSD to cope with XML's with and without the wrapper element.

I tried to add an xsd:element without name, but that does not work:

```
<xsd:element type="address_Type" />
```

I could not find an xsd: entity with type attribute to point to the complexType  other than xsd:element.

My question is if there still is a method to re-use the complexType for the last XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to compose new content models from existing content models without wrapper elements, consider using the `xs:group` mechanism:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:element name="user" type="user" />

  <xsd:complexType name="user">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" />
      <!-- 
         ...
         Many more xsd:element or xsd:groups might appear here.
         ...
      -->
      <xsd:group ref="address"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:group name="address">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:group>  

</xsd:schema>
```

---

If you'd like to allow the wrapper optionally, you could use `xsd:choice`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="user" type="user" />

  <xsd:complexType name="user">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:group ref="address"/>
        <xsd:element name="address">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:group ref="address"/>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:group name="address">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:group>  

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer because it shows the essential trick with group. I also added my own answer for a complete solution, and a chance to others to add feedback.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've also updated the answer to show a concise way to allow the wrapper element optionally.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer of kjhughes, I expanded my XSD to accomodate XML with and without wrapper element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="usera" type="usera" />
  <xsd:element name="userb" type="userb" />
  <!-- ==== xml format without wrapper element ==== -->
  <xsd:complexType name="usera">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:group ref="address_Group" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!-- === xml format with wrapper element ==== -->
  <xsd:complexType name="userb">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="address">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:group ref="address_Group" />
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!-- ==== database record type for table Address ==== -->
  <xsd:group name="address_Group">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:group>
</xsd:schema>
```

It can validate this XML without wrapper element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<usera>
  <username>Albert Einstein</username>
  <!-- without address tag -->
  <street>Main Street</street>
  <city>Ghost Town</city>
  <state>Up State</state>
</usera>
```

and also this XML with wrapper element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<userb>
  <username>Albert Einstein</username>
  <!-- with address tag -->
  <address>
    <street>Main Street</street>
    <city>Ghost Town</city>
    <state>Up State</state>
  </address>
</userb>
```

All with only one description of the database record table in the XSD. I checked that this works with creating C# classes using XSD.EXE and with deserializing.

Comment: You might prefer to use `xs:choice` to express the optionality of the wrapper element.  I've added an example to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66287363/290085) to show the details.

Comment: @kjhughes Great, that gives me a 'choice' of options! Monday at work I will check if 'group' creates c# classes and if deserialization works